# Why doesn't Note 2(N7100) recognize external hard drive but Honor 6 does?

Tags: samsung, samsung-galaxy-note-2, usb-on-the-go, huawei-honor-6

I have two cell phones Note2 and Honor 6. Both are rooted, and run 4.4.2
Both have a battery of same capacity 3100mAh.
I can connect any of two external hard drives WD passport and WD Elements of 1 TB capacity (both are NTFS formatted and do not have provision for external powering on)  through OTG cable on  Honor 6 and transfer files 
But when I connect to  Note2 through same OTG cable,  the  external hard drive LED flickers and can't view the  contents of either drive.

Changing OTG cables,  using multiple apps from play store to manage OTG  mounting did not change anything

I read on some forum that  note 2 battery capacity is not enough to power on the external hard drive for normal operations and is just enough to recognize the  drive,  hence the flickering. This was not substantiated by any technical explanation.  Besides,  Honor 6 also has the same battery capacity!!! So this explanation doesn't sound logical unless am missing something

Would welcome a technical explanation for this please

Edit: situation is the same if the external drive is formatted in FAT32

Thanks

Comment: Most likely it's the file system being used. NTFS support rarely is available on Android devices. To verify that, you could create another partition on that drive using a supported file system, such as FAT32 or EXT3, put some files on it, and try if those are seen.

Comment: Honor 6 have 3 GB RAM, But Note2 have only 2 GB RAM

Comment: Thanks @izzy .  Should have clarified this in the question. I have yet another drive formatted on FAT32 and even that is not recognised.  BTW are you suggesting that honor 6 has the added capability to read NTFS?  Purely my opinion, without any technical backing but Huawei phones aren't really that inclusive

Comment: @TintuMon thanks.  Agreed. Does RAM play a role in this?  Would like to know more

Comment: Well, if the drive is formatted using NTFS, and the Honor can read it – isn't that the logic conclusion? If it would *not* support NTFS, it were not able to. So either the drive doesn't use NTFS, or the Honor supports it, or you're seeing ghosts. Your choice :)

Comment: @izzy. Guess I didn't word my  earlier response appropriately.  Sorry for that.  It comes out as rude without meaning to.  But that doesn't clarify why note 2 can't see the FAT32 formatted drive

Comment: No offense meant or taken – so nothing to apologize for :) And yes, I fully agree: it does not explain why the FAT32 drive is not recognized. I'm out at that point, and have to leave the scene to someone more familiar with the "hardware related part".