# Can we run android os completely from RAM?

Tags: ram

I asked this question on Stack Overflow but got no response and I'm not sure if this is the right place to ask this question... but anyways here goes -

**Is it possible to run Android completely from RAM?**

Seeing as some smartphones these days have almost **4GB of RAM**, is it possible to run at least older android versions or some other lightweight linux OS completely from RAM?

If yes, what are the limitations?

Comment: I don't think it is possible for reasons mentioned [here](http://android.stackexchange.com/a/41223), while the question is different but the answer should be valid in this case too

Comment: I guess it is theoretically possible. Maybe not on all devices. You can run Android on pc's using android-x86 or Remix OS or similar. The accepted answer in beeshyams' very interesting linked question is from 2013, a more recent answer suggests it might be possible.

Comment: The kernel and the most important system parts are already in a ram-disk loaded at boot. Therefore one could say that it is already running from RAM.

Comment: @Robert ` Therefore one could say....` I guess that would be one who don't know what is talking about... all the OS(es) run the kernel from RAM. That doesn't mean the entire OS runs from ram. Remove the flash drive after the OS starts up and then if nothing crashes you could say that you run it from RAM.